Is $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ a local ring where $K$ is field?
I came a cross with this question "Is $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ a local ring where $K$ is field?" This is a ring of formal power series in which the terms are generated by $X^2$ and $X^3$ i.e. This ring contains the polynomials of degree $\ge 2$ with constants.
I know the following

If $R$ is a local ring, then $R[[x]]$ is also a local ring.

But I have two indeterminates $X^2$ and $X^3$, so I couldn't be sure that I can use this fact or not.
On the other hand, it is clear that $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ has the ideal $(X^2,X^3)$ which is maximal as the quotient will be $K$ which is a field.
My question is how can I show that this is the only maximal ideal that $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ has?

Note that $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ is the ring of power series of the form $f=\sum_{n\geq0}c_nX^n$ with $c_n\in K$ and $c_1=0$. The ideal $(X^2,X^3)$ consists precisely of those power series with $c_0=0$. You want to show that if $c_0\neq0$ then $f$ is a unit. This follows easily from the fact that for any $g\in K[[X]]$ you have
$$(1-Xg)\sum_{n\geq0}(Xg)^n=1.$$

You basically showed that if $f \in K[[X^2,X^3]]$ then either $f$ or $1-f$ is unit, right?

Btw, the ideal $(X^2,X^3)=X^2K[[X]]$. That is $c_0=0,c_1=0$.

@Elise9 That's also true I guess. I'd rather view it as showing that $f$ is a unit if $f(0)\neq0$. You can then scale to have $f(0)=1$, which is what I use here.

@Elise9 And indeed your second comment is correct.

Can I easily say that $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ is local because every element $K[[X^2,X^3]] \setminus (X^2,X^3)=K$ is unit?

Depends on your audience, I guess. That  fact immediately makes $(X^2,X^3)$ the unique maximal ideal, if you know that it is a proper ideal, i.e. that it is not the entire ring. Pretty obvious to me but maybe that's something you need to prove.

For me, maximality is pretty obvious but I can't directly say that this is the only maximal ideal i.e. why it is local?

If there were another maximal ideal $P$, then there would be some element $p\in P$ with $p\notin (X^2,X^3)$. But then $p$ is a unit and so $P$ is not a maximal ideal, a contradiction.

The candidates for $p$ are either constant or $a+bx+\dots$ where $a,b\in K$. If $p\in K$ then definitely it is unit. How do you know the elements containing the term $a+bx$ has an inverse? e.g. what is the inverse of $x$?

@Elise9 $X$ is not in the ring $K[![X^2,X^3]!]$.

You are absolutely right, my mistake.
